# RegEx Group Name Error

Tags: c#, regex, msdn

The following line of code:

```
Match match = Regex.Match(json, ".*\"access_token\":\"(?<;token>;.*?)\".*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Is giving me the error:

ArgumentException: parsing ".*\"access_token\":\"(?<;token>;.*?)\".*" - Invalid group name: Group names must begin with a word character.

I took this code directly from:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn546687.aspx

Comment: I read through to the bottom and see that a user also provided the solution.  Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using Regex instead of deserializing the JSON?

Comment: They also said —"Just saying that this json notation is so poor in data contract that becomes very prone error."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a `;` character between the `?<` and the `token`

```
(?<;token>;
   ^ here
```

Remove this and it will eliminate the error.

Comment: I will accept as soon as SO permits based on the time limit.  Thanks.

Comment: Both the semi colons needs to be removed.

Comment: @Ganesh second semicolon didn't cause the error. Second one could be the part of the regex.

Comment: @SabujHassan, it would eliminate the ArgumentException but would not extract the value though.

Answer (score 0):

In your RegEx you address your group naming it ";token" (between < and >). It's illegal. Use "token" instead.

```
Match match = Regex.Match(json, ".*\"access_token\":\"(?<token>;.*?)\".*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 0):

That regex is not correct. There are semi colons in it that needs to be removed.

Use this:

```
Match match = Regex.Match(json, ".*\"access_token\":\"(?<token>.*?)\".*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```